# node.js+mysql+mocha no response when my query statement is variable

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to use node.js with mocha and mysql, but when I give a fixed value to query such as "select * from user where name=test" it can work normally but when I give a variable "email" to query then it no any response.

```
var time = Date.now();
var email = time.toString() + '@mailinator.com';
beforeEach(function () {
    conn = mysql.createConnection({
        host: '**',
        user: '**',
        password: '**',
        port: '**',
        database: '**',
    });
    conn.connect();
})
afterEach(function (done) {
    var query = `select * from user where email='${email}'`;
    conn.query(query, function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
    });     
    conn.end(done);
})
```

Comment: Please ask an explicit question !

Comment: thanks, and it was fixed after I use setTimeout()